# Aspnet WebForms file not find error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm getting a problem in my aspnet webform app. When I'm not logged in, it redirects to the `/Account/Login.aspx` file as usual.

I get the 404 file not found error URL: `/Order/Account/Login`

But the file is there! It was working until yesterday and I did not change much.

When in debug mode, I get an error in the `global.asax` method:

```
void Application_Error( object sender , EventArgs e )
{
    var ex = Server.GetLastError();
    if( ex != null )
    {
        Session["Erro"] = ex.InnerException;
    }
}
```

Where ex = file not found.

What could be wrong, or where can I get more information in the app?

EDIT:
when i get the error in the browser, the url is:

localhost:10536/Order/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fGuazzelliOrder%2fAccount%2fLogin.aspx

Comment: Have you checked your routing configs to find where the actual file should be for that url?

Comment: check `Order/Account/Login.aspx` page is exists

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC with the ASPX view engine? Or is this purely an webform application? (The tags have me a little confused)

Comment: @StevenV i edited the post with the url, im using with aspx.

Comment: @Murali it exists. I can see it in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `localhost:10536/Order/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fGuazzelliOrder%2fAccount%2fLogin.aspx` I'm assuming you have a redirect that is missing the .aspx extension of the file, so it can't find Login.aspx. Check the code that's performing the redirect.

Also, you should make it clear whether you are using ASP.NET Web Forms on ASP.NET MVC. Your tags on your question indicate both.

Comment: Sorry, i put ASP.NET MVC because i thought it could be a generic ASP.NET error.